# What does this regular expression mean /^[\w0-9.-]{1,}@[A-z0-9]{1,}.[A-z]{3}$/

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

Can someone elaborate the following regular expression:

```
/^[\w0-9.-]{1,}@[A-z0-9]{1,}.[A-z]{3}$/
```

and also give some sample strings that satisfy this regular expression?
Thanks

Comment: looks like this is validating an email-adress

Comment: is this your homework ?

Comment: Read the description on the right - https://regex101.com/r/wO6aN1/1

Comment: What that regex means is that its author doesn't know anything about regexes.  `\w` already matches digits, `{1,}` is the same as `+`, the second  `.` should be `\.`, and `[A-z]` is **not** how you match letters case-insensitively.  And if the regex is meant to validate email addresses, the author doesn't know anything about those, either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a crude regex to check for an email address. Not the proper complete one, mind you (it's a **lot** longer).

Answer (score 0):

- `^` beginning of string
- `[\w0-9.-]` - *word character*, a digit, a dot or a dash. Doesn't make that much sense as *word character*s include digits too, so it can be simplified to `[\w.-]`
- `{1,}` - one or more of those. There is an equivalent `+`, it's better to use that instead
- `@` - at sign
- `[A-z0-9]` - a terrible idea to mix capital and lower case letters. As it is right now, this means *all ascii characters from `A` to `z` plus digits*
- `.` - any character. I'm guessing it should have been a literal dot - `\.`
- `[A-z]{3}` - three characters, again as above
- `$` - end of line

---

So my guess is that this was a poor's man attempt at email validation. Here is the simplified version with the `[A-z]` shenanigan fixed:

```
/^[\w.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$/
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/dR6pB4/2)

---

As for something which satisfies the original regex - `.@A.AAA`

Comment: Oh thank you very much!

Comment: @NeedingHelp, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [http://regexper.com](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B%5Cw0-9.-%5D%7B1%2C%7D%40%5BA-z0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5C.%5BA-z%5D%7B3%7D%24%2F) which illustrates regular expressions (Note, I fixed the escaping of the period for you):

[image: Regex]

From the illustration you can see it is checking for:

1. The start of the string
2. One or more characters of: a word character, period or dash
3. Followed by a single "@" symbol
4. Followed by one or more characters within the ranges of A-z or 0-9
5. Followed by a period
6. Followed by three characters within the range of A-z
7. The end of the string

as @Kayaman mentions, it's a crude regular expression for an email address, though is an encompassing expression to find *any* valid email.